# Subsonic 3 ActiveRecord Test Feature Doesn't Support Linq?

Tags: unit-testing, subsonic3

According to this [blog post](http://blog.wekeroad.com/subsonic/subsonic-30-activerecord/), the ActiveRecord Test features in Subsonic 3 don't support linq. If this is true, it would seem to really constrain the usefulness of the Test features. Is there a workaround, or am I just misreading what was said?

Comment: What specific point in that blog post makes you think you can't use LINQ with the test features?

Comment: Where it says: "The interception will work 90% of the time for your application – however there are some circumstances where we can’t intercept the DB call" ... "One of these places is our Linq implementation. It doesn’t know what’s calling it or why – so it won’t know it’s ActiveRecord and moreover won’t know if it’s under test – so we can’t intercept it."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like development and interest in SubSonic has dropped a lot with usable EF versions and NoSQL databases. I think this question is moot.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be misreading as you can use LINQ with the ActiveRecord test Repository.  Basically all SS does is mock up a repo with in memory List<> objects.